# How to Prevent Duplicate Entries to enter to delta lake of Azure Storage

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

I Have a Dataframe stored in the format of delta into Adls, now when im trying to append new updated rows to that delta lake it should, Is there any way where i can delete the old existing record in delta and add the new updated Record.

There is a unique Column for the schema of DataFrame stored in Delta. by which we can check whether the record is updated or new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a task for [Merge command](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-update.html#upsert-into-a-table-using-merge) - you define condition for merge (your unique column) and then actions.  In SQL it could look as following (`column` is your unique column, and `updates` could be your dataframe registered as temporary view):

```sql
MERGE INTO destination
USING updates
ON destination.column = updates.column
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET *
WHEN NOT MATCHED
  THEN INSERT *
```

In Python it could look as following:

```py
from delta.tables import *

deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, "/data/destination/")

deltaTable.alias("dest").merge(
    updatesDF.alias("updates"),
    "dest.column = updates.column") \
  .whenMatchedUpdateAll() \
  .whenNotMatchedInsertAll() \
  .execute()
```

Comment: Hi Alex Ott , Your solution really worked thanks for That. Is there any, way, we  can reduce our delta table consideration , like changing it to, to into consideration only particular partitions rather than entire delta table. That would really help

Comment: You just need to construct ON condition correctly

Comment: Hi Alex, Can you explain it more briefly with respect to syntax. I was using python code mentioned by you." deltaTable = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, "/data/destination/")", so can we mention here anything rather than reading entire table read only specific partitions of delta table ,since as the days pass data would be increasing.

Comment: expand condition `"dest.column = updates.column"` to include check on the partition key